# I want to select all table field with left join 2nd table in order by first table 1st column

Tags: codeigniter

below code

```
 $getQueList = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions_master order by questions_master.question_id desc LEFT JOIN users_master ON questions_master.userId = users_master.userId ");
```

I want to get result as per questions_master.question_id in descending order

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query you have to use for getting result questions_master.question_id in descending order

```
SELECT * 
FROM questions_master 
LEFT JOIN users_master 
ON questions_master.userId = users_master.userId 
ORDER BY questions_master.question_id desc
```

Order by clause comes at the end.

Comment: This query return 1 as output not table fetch data

Comment: It not fetch table data only return value 1 as boolean